# Liquibase : change column type in Java

Tags: java, liquibase

I am using **`liquibase:diff`** to update my database if one entity is modified.
How can I do in my Java entity if I want to transform `VARCHAR(255)` to `TEXT` in the *MySQL* column type.
In Java I only have a `String` type for my property.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JPA/Hibernate annotations, you can do this

```
 @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
```

but this would be database specific, and not portable across databases which don't have a "TEXT" column type.

A more portable solution would be to use the @lob annotation like

```
@Lob 
private String text;
```

this should generate TEXT or LONGTEXT data type.

Comment: The change is not detected, it's generating an empty changelog file.

Comment: @user1260928 same issue I am facing, how did you solve it?